# Flutter - Getting Seed colors back from Tonal Palette M3

Tags: flutter, colors, material-you

M3 colorscheme provides all properties like, `primary`, `onPrimary`, `secondary`, `onSecondary` etc, but they are generally not exactly the same from the colors they are generated from, i.e., the generated colors are different from the seed values.

For Example

TonalPallete of `0064ff` as primary color will be changed to `0054d8` or somewhat similiar.

This is how I am getting a palette from the color

```
  TonalPalette get tonalPalette {
    final cam16 = Cam16.fromInt(value);
    return TonalPalette.of(cam16.hue, cam16.chroma);
  }
```

This extension creates Palette which can be used to create the colorScheme (primary40 for primary, primary100 for onPrimary, primary90 for primaryContainer etc.)

For Reference :

[image: M3]

Real Question :

I need to generate the Seed color from the TonalPallete colors, Kind of backtracking the original/seed color from the generated tonal primary color. Anyway we can do it. Thanks.

Edit : Just to let you know, I dont have a TonalPalette as the object but only its values.

Answer (score 0):

Got to know something from the friend and he stated

> A color consists of chroma, hue, and luminosity. we're
> intentionally losing the luminosity of the color to generate the tonal
> palette which is information lost. Since there is no way other than
> magic to get that value back, it's impossible to trace back to the
> seed color
>
> What we know for sure, is that the seed color will have the same
> hue and chroma, but some luminosity that we don't know of.

So we actually can't have it back :(